# SFTP inbound adapter and transaction synchronization

Tags: transactions, spring-integration, thread-synchronization

I am using SFTP inbound adapter with custom filter. What I like to implement is, if filter accept the file then let it move through message flow where that file will be delivered to spring batch job using "batch-integration:job-launching-gateway" which is working fine. Now problem is, if filter rejects it then I want it to move to some dir like "/failed/" also if during batch processing if jdbc transaction fails then also i want it to move to "/failed/" dir so that we handle them later. How can we synchronize jdbc transaction with this scenario in spring integration.

I read this doc(http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html) in spring integration but not clear about, a sample app would be perfect otherwise some hints are also ok.

Configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sftp.test" />
<import resource="beans-context.xml" />

<!-- Default poller -->
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="5000"/>


<!-- SFTP inbound poller -->
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
    channel="fileMessageChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    local-directory="${test.sftp.local.dir}" remote-directory="${test.sftp.remote.dir}"
    remote-file-separator="/" auto-create-local-directory="true"
    delete-remote-files="true" filename-pattern="*" local-filter="testFileFilter"
    preserve-timestamp="true" temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    >

    <int:poller cron="${test.file.poll.frequency}"
        max-messages-per-poll="1">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            synchronization-factory="syncFactory" /> 
    </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory
    id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo('/tmp/dds/test/success/' + payload.name)"
        channel="committedChannel" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo('/tmp/dds/test/failed/' + payload.name)"
        channel="rolledBackChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="committedChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="committedChannel" />


<int:channel id="rolledBackChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="rolledBackChannel" />


<!-- Channel where message with file name will be dropped by inbound sftp 
    channel adapter -->
<int:channel id="fileMessageChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<!-- Transform spring integration message to job launch request -->
<int:transformer input-channel="fileMessageChannel"
    output-channel="jobRequestChannel" id="jobLaunchMessageTransformer">
    <bean class="com.sftp.test.test.util.FileMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="testJob" />
        <property name="fileParameterName" value="fileName" />
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<!-- Job request channel -->
<int:channel id="jobRequestChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<!-- The JobLaunchingGateway is used to launch Batch Jobs. Internally it 
    delegates to a JobLaunchingMessageHandler. -->
<batch-integration:job-launching-gateway
    request-channel="jobRequestChannel" reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />

<!-- job response channel -->
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<!-- Logging response received from job on jobLaunchReplyChannel -->

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"   ref="fileProcessAdapter"    method="moveFile"/>
```

Comment: I found this example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tx-synch but if I follow that, before my job picks up message it changes the file name so later on failing the job.

Comment: You need to show your configuration.

Comment: Added config. Also my transaction manager is associated with jdbc datasource where my job is inserting rows. So what i want to achieve is that if jdbc trans failed then renamed file to ".failed" else ".success"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `QueueChannel`s. As soon as you hand off the request to another thread, the poller transaction will "commit".

You need to run the job on the poller thread (remove the `<queue/>` elements from the channels). Add a task executor to the poller if you want to run multiple jobs concurrently.

Also, in order to reject and rename a file, you can't use an internal filter because filtered files don't produce a message. You could either do the rename within your filter, or use an `AcceptAllFileListFilter` in the adapter and use a `<filter/>` in the flow (configured to throw an exception on rejection).